# a list of checkboxes

Tags: grails

I have two domain classes

```
class Contract {
    String number
    static hasMany = [statements:Statement]
}

class Statement {
    String code
    static hasMany = [contracts:Contract]
}
```

I would like to show all statements available in my gsp with a checkbox next to each, allowing the user to choose which statements are applicable to the contract. So something like:

```
[ ] Statement Code 1
[ ] Statement Code 2
[ ] Statement Code 3
```

I started off with this:

```
<g:each in="${Statement.list()}" var="statement" status="i">
    <g:checkBox name="statements[${i}].id" value="${statement.id}" checked="${contractInstance.statements.contains(statement.id)}" />
    <label for="statements[${i}]">${statement.code}</label>
</g:each>
```

But i just cannot get a list of checked statements to the controller (there are `null` elements in the list, there are repeated statements...).

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible, but it does require a bit of a hack. First off, every checkbox must have the same name, "statements":

```
<g:each in="${org.example.Statement.list(sort: 'id', order: 'asc')}" var="statement" status="i">
    <g:checkBox name="statements" value="${statement.id}" checked="${contract.statements.contains(statement)}" />
    <label for="statements">${statement.content}</label>
</g:each>
```

Second, in the controller you have to remove the "_statements" property before binding:

```
def contract = Contract.get(params.id)
params.remove "_statements"
bindData contract, params
contract.save(failOnError: true)
```

The check box support hasn't been designed for this use case, hence the need for a hack. The multi-select list box is the one typically used for this type of scenario.

Comment: `params.remove "_statements"` did the trick. i did however write my own tag which builds checkboxes without the hidden _ parameter.

Comment: It is odd that the checkboxes all needed the same name, but that worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to get the list of Id's in this case.

```
<g:each var="book" in="${books}">
    <g:checkBox name="bookIds" value="${book.id}" ...
</g:each>
```

Command Object:

```
class BookCommand {
    List<Serializable> bookIds
}
```

In controller action:

```
BookCommand bc ->
    author.books = Book.getAll(bc.bookIds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the checkbox to something like this.

```
<g:checkBox name="statements.${statement.id}" value="true" checked="${contractInstance.statements.contains(statement)?:''}" />
```

and then in the controller, in `params.statements` you will get a list with the IDs of the checked statements.

Also notice the `?:''` in the checked property, it's a good idea to add it because any value(even 'false') in the checked property is interpreted as checked.

Comment: Using this approach (and checking statements 3, 4 and 6), `params.statements` looks like this: `statements:[_3:, _4:, _5:, _6:, _1:, _2:, 6:true, 4:true, 3:true]` and it doesn't bind to `contractInstance`. All I really want is `params.statements` to be `[3, 4, 6]` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mapping request directly to `Contract`? It's much more secure to map incoming request into an `Command object`.

As about mapping a list - values are mapped only to existing elements. I mean it cannot create new list elements. You need to prepare it before mapping. If you know that there is always 3 elements, you can make:

```
class ContractCommand {

   List statements = [
       new Statement(),
       new Statement(),
       new Statement(),
   ]
}
```

and map request to this object