# how to properly render checkboxes and get a list of which checkboxes have been selected in Grails

Tags: grails, checkbox, gsp

I have tried for over a month get the correct rendering, binding and listing of selected checkboxes in grails (please see this link: [How to get a list of checked boxes in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297035/how-to-get-a-list-of-checked-boxes-in-grails/36324795?noredirect=1#comment60336306_36324795)).

I can get a list of checkboxes from the controller with this code:
package frametest

import groovy.io.FileType

```
class Read_dirController {

    def index() { 

        def list = []

        def dir = new File("/Users/ironmantis7x/Documents/business/test_files/APITest/utils")
        dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
          list << file
        }

        list.each {
            println it.name.replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, '')
          }

        render(view: "index",  model: [name:list.name])

        params.list('fileName')

    }
def uri() {
        def api_link = String
        render(view: "index",  model: [name:url_link])

    }


        def displayForm() { }

        /*def submitForm(String fileName) {
            render params.list('fileName')
            //request.getParameterValues('fileName')
        }*/

        def submitForm() {
            def values = request.getParameterValues('fileName')
            //render(view: "submitForm")
            params.remove "_"
            render (view: "submitForm", model: [params.list('values')])
        }
}
```

that works fine....
I can display it in the gsp with this code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>API Automation Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body">
    <h2>Automation Test Page</h2>
    <h4>Please choose test(s) below ...</h4>

    <br>
    <h3>Tests</h3>
    <br>
    <div>
    <style>
    .columns3 {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3; }
    </style>
        <g:form action="submitForm">
            <ul class="columns3">
                <g:each in="${name}" var="fileName" >
                    <g:checkBox value="${false}" name="${fileName}" id="${fileName.replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, '')}" /> ${fileName.replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, '')}<br>
                </g:each> 
            </ul>
            <br>
            <br>
            <g:submitButton name="Submit"/>
        </g:form>   
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
<%--        <h4>Quick Test</h4>--%>
<%--        Input API manually: <g:textField name="url_link" value="${api_link}" /> --%>
<%--        <g:submitButton name="qtest" value="go!" />--%>
<%--        <br>--%>
<%--        <br>--%>
        API Output Response: <br>
        <g:textArea name="name" rows="300" cols="3000" style="resize: none;"/>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is this:
when I select a set of checkbox(es), I get a blank list (here is the submit form gsp):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>API Automation Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body">
    <h2>Automation Test Page</h2>
    <h4>You have chosen the test(s) below.</h4>

    <br>
    <h3>Tests Chosen:</h3>
    <br>
    <div>
            <%--<ul class="columns3">
                <g:each in="${name}" var="fileName">
                    <g:checkBox value="${false}" name="${ 'fileName'}"/> ${fileName.replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, '')}<br>
                </g:each> 
            </ul>
            --%>

            <g:each in="${values}" var="tests">
                <ul>
                    ${'tests'} <br>
                </ul>
            </g:each> 

            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

when I check the binding through Chrome I get this list detail for the Form Data:

```
._DS_Store:
login._sh:
login.sh:on
Submit:Submit
```

I am kind of lost on what my error is.
Can some one help me with a detailed explanation of the proper way to render a list of checkboxes and how to correctly render a list of selected checkboxes as well.

I am still new to grails. But I find it a very powerful and rich tool to do a lot of stuff.

Thanks!!

ironmantis7x

Comment: in regards to rendering a list of selected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737748/a-list-of-checkboxes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364227/my-checkbox-pass-value-even-unchecked-grails

Comment: @tim_yates: can you make this an answer so I can select it as the correct answer and up-vote it? thx.
i believe that this is the correct answer.